# Append value to ComboBoxEdit in DevExpress grid

Tags: silverlight, autocomplete, combobox, devexpress

I am doing Silverligth 4 App
I am using DevExpress Gridcontrol . I have 4 columns. I have placed [ComboBoxEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument4910) as editor in one column. ComboxBoxEdit's autocomplete feature is enabled.

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid_presentingcomplaints">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Complaints" Header="Complaints/Disease">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings PopupMaxHeight="150" DisplayMember="Text" AutoComplete="True" />
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Duration" Header="Duration (For)" />
        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Period" FieldName="Period" />
        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Details" FieldName="Details" />
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView Name="tableView3" ShowGroupPanel="False" NewItemRowPosition="Top" />
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

i have attached the combox item source as below

```
void cmn_obj_GetComplaintsListCompleted(object sender, GetComplaintsListCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Error == null) {
        ((ComboBoxEditSettings)grid_presentingcomplaints.Columns["Complaints"].EditSettings).ItemsSource = e.Result;
    }
}
```

Evrything works fine no probz till here.

But when i type into combobox the autocomplete feature works as normal. but say i want to type in value which is not preset . it doesn't allow. **i want type a new value if it is not present in the autocomplete list.**

Any ideas?? Need a solution very badly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the Incemental Filtering feature instead of the AutoComplete in this case:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Complaints" Header="Complaints/Disease">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings IncrementalFiltering="True" ImmediatePopup="True"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Comment: It doesn't help. The combobox should accept a new value if it is not present in it's itemsource.. eg a,b,c is the itemsource of the combobox. say i type **'d'** . In this case the input **'d'** is not being accepted by comboxbox since there is not 'd' value in it's itemsource.

Comment: Have you really tried this approach? When the incremental filtering is enabled the comboboxedit accept all input as possible value. The items source is automatically filtered by input so user can quickly select a value from itemsource by a few first letters. Unlike this one the autocomplete feature does not accept any values that not presented in itemsource.

Comment: It works to me when I've used a simple string as a type for Complaints property and array of strings as a itemssource (without DisplayMember="Text"). Please clarify you case with more details, because it is not quite clear which data type you've realy used

Comment: let me be more clear. Say my item source contains string values "nut","bolt","screws","hammer"  . say i check for the value "nail" ,but it's not present in the itemsource. so i would like force in to type the value "nail" in the comboxeditor. The comboxeditor must accept this new value, which in my case is not working. basically new value can be inputted. Hope i am clear.